# MongoDB, is there a statement similar to if then elif in sql?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Query is to find people whose age is shown and if their grade is 5 or higher then they will get honours, othewise fail. Can I use $cond with find?

```
db.test.find({age:{$exists:true}},{$cond: {if: "grade":5, then:"Honours" : true, else: "Honours" : "fail"}})
```

I also tried

```
db.test.find({$and: [{age:{$exists:true}}, {grade: {$gte:"5"}}]}, {$set:{"Honours":"true"}}, {multi:true})
```

But neither come close. Any help/direction is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check this.

```
  db.test.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "age": {
        "$exists": true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "Honours": {
        $switch: {
          branches: [
            {
              case: {
                "$gte": [
                  "$grade",
                  5
                ]
              },
              then: "true"
            }
          ],
          default: "fail"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

`.find` projection only allows include / exclude fields, neither transform them nor add new field. Use `MongoDB aggregation`

```
db.test.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      age: {
        $exists: true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      Honours: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $gte: [
              "$grade",
              5
            ]
          },
          true,
          "fail"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9195SgvrkPW)

Comment: @bexi I've updated my answer, I didn't understand what you were trying to do until now